# How can I get my Java application listed if right-click on folder in Windows?

Tags: java, windows, shortcut, right-click

How can I get my Java application listed if right-click on folder in Windows, would be great if could use same method for Windows XP, Windows 7 and Windows 8.

**This questions should not be closed as a duplicate because the other question does not explain how to link a context menu to a folder only to a file of particular suffix (.doc etc)**

Comment: What does your app. do with the directory?  Why a directory and not particular file types (which is fairly easy to implement)?

Comment: Its is for correcting metadata in audio files, but in normal use the user selects a folder containing audio rather than the actual audio files themselves.

Comment: The answer you link to does not give a solution for adding a context menu for a folder.